# when exponential curve fit is corrupted by noise

Tags: curve-fitting

I met a problem when doing curve fit with this equation

```
y=a*exp(-x/b)
```

x is fixed `x=[13 26 39 52 65 78 91]`. y is the input. a and b are unknows. b is the output. I use LSQ estimation to do curve fitting, and add a constraint for the output b: b should be in the range of `[0,1000]`.

Now the system works like this: when I have an input sequence like

```
y=[460 434 288 218 164 114 89]
```

The output is `b=51.46`, which is good.

If the input sequence is

```
y=[599 640 592 609 550 588 573 626]
```

The estimation result is `b=1000`. This is also good. No problem.

But when I input a pure noise sequence:

```
y=[24 19 31 5 27 31 17]
```

The result I get from my curve fitting algorithm is `b=1000`. In this case, the output `b` is a very high signal, and this is not acceptable for the system. I expect to output a low value of `b`, say `b = 0`.

I tried to add a threshold on y, say

```
if y<50 then b=0
```

But the system is not very stable. The noise level changes from time to time. Is there other way to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Frist, note that this category of problems commonly appears in literature in terms of [logistic growth model](https://www.math.duke.edu//education/ccp/materials/diffeq/logistic/logi1.html) (or see [here](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&ved=0CHsQFjAI&url=http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF-MAT2351/v11/chapter9.pdf&ei=gsUjUaOvMYmg0QW2p4C4CQ&usg=AFQjCNGINTuct5EY9_SXcYG_GWBTeAJCpg&sig2=W_0baO6nhCROSy1iKg3QlQ&bvm=bv.42553238,d.d2k)). I believe your specific  problem should be  considered in the context of the [Mixed Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model),   a statistical model containing both fixed effects and random effects.

More concretely, you might use  Matlab's [nlmefit](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/stats/nlmefit.html) from its statistics toolbox.
A bird-view of nlme can be found in this [ppt](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://bcs.siu.edu/facultypages/young/Modeling/NLME.ppt&ei=PcQjUe2MN6LK0AXe1oGgBA&usg=AFQjCNFnAgkdBbFFjXhfupVtuC9yA-lC1g&sig2=ZNAUYFJOCHPXJMdhp_TFKA&bvm=bv.42553238,d.d2k).